# How to refine elasticsearch query by date and search term

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have Elastic 7.11.x - I'm running the query below, and it's working, but it's returning too much data - how do I add the date range filter to this type of query?  I found some examples here but they are old and not working.

I want to return records that match the "source" field and are within a @timestamp range (8/20/2021 - 8/21/2021 MST)

```
POST metrics-general-dev-000049/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "source": {
        "query": "investigation-data-depot"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "time_buckets": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "fixed_interval": "1d",
        "extended_bounds": {
          "min": "now-2d"
        },
        "min_doc_count": 0
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine with a range filter using the bool query:

```json
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "filter": [
      { "match": ... },
      { "range": ... }
    ]
  }
}
```

Ref:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/query-dsl-range-query.html#ranges-on-dates

and

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Comment: Not sure why I can't read and understand their documentation - somehow it escaped me.  Thx